# How to assign correctly low, mid and high color limits with heatmply R package for an interactive heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmaply

based on a current visualization project for ngs experiments and functional enrichment analysis results, I'm trying create an interactive heatmap plot of specific biological processes-names in the rows, and specific annotated genes in the columns, using the R package heatmaply-the values are essentially the log2 fold changes, either positive or negative values, with 0 denoting that there is no correlation/association of a specific gene with a specific biological mechanism:

```
dd <- read.table("bim.test.trial.txt",sep="\t",header = T,row.names=1)

 head(dd)
       regulation.of.defense.response.to.virus
Ifng                                  3.332965
Il6                                   0.000000
Havcr2                                2.436155
Lgals9                                2.058915
Tlr3                                  0.000000
Tlr9                                  0.000000
       regulation.of.cell.adhesion alpha.beta.T.cell.differentiation
Ifng                      3.332965                          3.332965
Il6                       3.994865                          3.994865
Havcr2                    2.436155                          0.000000
Lgals9                    2.058915                          0.000000
Tlr3                      0.000000                          0.000000
Tlr9                      0.000000                          0.000000
...

heatmaply(t(dd),
          fontsize_col = 7.5,
          col = cool_warm(50),
          scale_fill_gradient_fun = ggplot2::scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid="white",high = "red", midpoint = 0, limits = c(-2, 2)),
          main = 'Trial_test_heatmap')

# also a reproducible example:

set.seed(256)
xx2 <- matrix(rnorm(16),8,8)

range(xx2)
[1] -1.867392  1.654713

#first heatmap

heatmaply(xx2,
fontsize_col = 7.5,
col = cool_warm(50),
scale_fill_gradient_fun = ggplot2::scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid="white",high = "red", midpoint = 0, limits = c(-1, 1)), main = 'Trial_test_heatmap')

# second

heatmaply(xx2,
fontsize_col = 7.5,
col = cool_warm(50),
scale_fill_gradient_fun = ggplot2::scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid="white",high = "red", midpoint = 0, limits = c(-2, 2)), main = 'Trial_test_heatmap')

sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Greek_Greece.1253  LC_CTYPE=Greek_Greece.1253   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Greek_Greece.1253 LC_NUMERIC=C                 
[5] LC_TIME=Greek_Greece.1253    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] heatmaply_0.15.2      viridis_0.5.1         viridisLite_0.3.0    
[4] plotly_4.8.0          ggplot2_3.1.0         circlize_0.4.5       
[7] ComplexHeatmap_1.20.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.0          tidyr_0.8.2         jsonlite_1.6       
 [4] foreach_1.4.4       gtools_3.8.1        shiny_1.2.0        
 [7] assertthat_0.2.0    stats4_3.5.0        yaml_2.2.0         
[10] robustbase_0.93-3   pillar_1.3.1        lattice_0.20-38    
[13] glue_1.3.0          digest_0.6.18       promises_1.0.1     
[16] RColorBrewer_1.1-2  colorspace_1.3-2    httpuv_1.4.5       
[19] htmltools_0.3.6     plyr_1.8.4          pkgconfig_2.0.2    
[22] GetoptLong_0.1.7    xtable_1.8-3        purrr_0.2.5        
[25] mvtnorm_1.0-8       scales_1.0.0        webshot_0.5.1      
[28] gdata_2.18.0        whisker_0.3-2       later_0.7.5        
[31] tibble_1.4.2        withr_2.1.2         nnet_7.3-12        
[34] lazyeval_0.2.1      mime_0.6            magrittr_1.5       
[37] crayon_1.3.4        mclust_5.4.2        MASS_7.3-51.1      
[40] gplots_3.0.1        class_7.3-14        Cairo_1.5-9        
[43] tools_3.5.0         registry_0.5        data.table_1.11.8  
[46] GlobalOptions_0.1.0 stringr_1.3.1       trimcluster_0.1-2.1
[49] kernlab_0.9-27      munsell_0.5.0       cluster_2.0.7-1    
[52] fpc_2.1-11.1        bindrcpp_0.2.2      compiler_3.5.0     
[55] caTools_1.17.1.1    rlang_0.3.0.1       iterators_1.0.10   
[58] rstudioapi_0.8      rjson_0.2.20        htmlwidgets_1.3    
[61] crosstalk_1.0.0     labeling_0.3        bitops_1.0-6       
[64] gtable_0.2.0        codetools_0.2-15    flexmix_2.3-14     
[67] TSP_1.1-6           reshape2_1.4.3      R6_2.3.0           
[70] seriation_1.2-3     gridExtra_2.3       knitr_1.21         
[73] prabclus_2.2-6      dplyr_0.7.8         bindr_0.1.1        
[76] KernSmooth_2.23-15  dendextend_1.9.0    shape_1.4.4        
[79] stringi_1.2.4       modeltools_0.2-22   Rcpp_1.0.0         
[82] gclus_1.3.1         DEoptimR_1.0-8      tidyselect_0.2.5   
[85] xfun_0.4            diptest_0.75-7
```

However, if you see my attached snapshot png image, the value 0-that is, the desired midpoint, is not shown as white in the heatmapbody, and there is no white color-also, as the plethora of discrete values-are zero in many genes, they are colored with a different color-that is blue defined in the low limit in the function scale_fill_gradient2 from ggplot2-

thus, there is a way to fix this issue ? and specify correctly low, mid and high ends of the color palette ?

Thank you in advance

Efstathios

[image: output of heatmply function]

Answer (score 1):

Your data range is wider (>2) than the color range (from -2 to 2).
I believe you're seeing a bug in the package. Please use a range in scale_fill_gradient_fun that includes ALL of your data. e.g.:

```
heatmaply(t(dd),
          fontsize_col = 7.5,
          col = cool_warm(50),
          scale_fill_gradient_fun = ggplot2::scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid="white",high = "red", midpoint = 0, limits = c(-4, 4)),
          main = 'Trial_test_heatmap')
```

Comment: Dear Tal, thank you for your suggestion-actually, i modified the limits as you mentioned, but unfortunately it did not changed-i also mention the range of the numeric values of the data frame: range(dd)
[1] -5.757946  9.125934

Comment: Please share a self contained reproducible example of the issue.

Comment: Dear Tal, actually i probably found the issue- i will add reproducible code additionally to the example above-when i used in the limits argument above values bigger than the numeric range-in my case -10,10, it fixed the issue-this is also feasible with the example-thus, if i want to use narrower limits, i could use an alternative strategy ? something like scaling the rows ? even if these are discrete numerical values and not continuous ?

Comment: You probably have some numerical accuracy issue if using range. Just add a tiny number and it should be enough (I guess).